# Add line number to output file

Tags: awk

How to modify my code adding the option to get the line number to the output

Here my inputs

**Input file**

```
39589 39461      3       2835       2.97           2.97                     
39591 39461      3       2835       3.90           3.89                     
39591 40071      3       2835       3.38           9.00                     
39595 39953      3       2835       3.91           3.91                     
39601 39593      3       2836       3.50          17.00                     
39603 38669      3       2836       3.43           3.43                     
39603 39233      3       2836       4.03           8.00
```

**My code**

```
awk 'BEGIN{                                                                 
    DASHES = sprintf ("%0*d",57, _)                                     
        gsub (/0/, "-", DASHES)                                             
    print DASHES                                                        
    printf("%8s%12s%9s%14s%14s \n","ID/ID","XCode","ID","Code-OK(m)","Co
    print DASHES                                                        
}                                                                           
{                                                                           
     diff=sqrt(($5-$6)^2)                                                   
     if(diff > 3.8)  printf("%5s %5s %6d %10d %10.2f %14.2f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$
}                                                                           
END{                                                                        
     print DASHES                                                       
}' file
```

**My output**

```
---------------------------------------------------------                   
   ID/ID       XCode       ID    Code-OK(m)   Code-Bad(m)                   
---------------------------------------------------------                   
39591 40071      3       2835       3.38           9.00                     
39601 39593      3       2836       3.50          17.00                     
39603 39233      3       2836       4.03           8.00                     
---------------------------------------------------------
```

**Output Desired**

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------             
     ID/ID       XCode       ID    Code-OK(m)   Code-Bad(m)             
  ---------------------------------------------------------             
1 39591 40071      3       2835       3.38           9.00               
2 39601 39593      3       2836       3.50          17.00               
3 39603 39233      3       2836       4.03           8.00               
  ---------------------------------------------------------
```

The number of line can reach till 4 dig that is the reason i keep 5 spaces for line number.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To clarify: is that meant to be the line number of the input (your desired output should show 3, 5, and 7 as the line numbers) or of the output (your desired output is accurate)?

Comment: tallungulate. No i dont want to print NR value. I want to have 1,2,3 as they are 3 records found .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
...                                                                     
($5-$6)^2 > 3.8^2  {                                                 
      printf("%d %5s %5s %6d %10d %10.2f %14.2f\n",++count,$1,$2,$3,...
}  
...
```

you can eliminate square root by comparing square values, also move the condition out of the statement block.

Comment: karakfa, I use the condition sqrt(($5-$6)^2)   to get allways integer value. Then if i use ($5-$6)^2 it is not same case..

Comment: The comparison is the same. It's a common trick to eliminate sqrt computation. You're trying to mimic absolute value in an expensive way. Doesn't matter for trivial cases, but a suggestion since this site is to promote knowledge...

Comment: Karakfa, appreciate the information about the common trick to eliminate sqrt computation. tks a lot